# Add a new root element for xml in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a String in java which is in the XML format. P**lease note it is not a xml file but a string in XML format.**

I need to append a new root element for that.

My xml

```
<Country>
  <Street>ABC</Street>
  <City>XYZ</Street>
</Country>
```

What I need is

```
<Location>
    <Country>
       <Street>ABC</Street>
       <City>XYZ</Street>
    </Country>
</Location>
```

I tried many ways and also this is related to my problem I posted earlier.

[Jaxb Marshals the same XML Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470012/jaxb-marshals-the-same-xml-message)[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470012/jaxb-marshals-the-same-xml-message)

Since I need a quick fix, thought of appending the root somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the indentation matter?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :(

Comment: You could just add 1 level worth of indentation after every `\n` character in your string (The indentation changes in your example, consider correcting that) and then prepend `<newRootTag>\n` and append `\n</newRootTag>`

Comment: @toastedDeli thanks for your suggestion. But my existing xml String is returned as an output of a method. So any suggestions on how to add indentation? Thank you btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more generic and better way of doing what you're trying to do but since the question is about specifically using a `String`...

In the comments, you said the indentation matters. That means you need to indent everything you have so far, i.e adding 2 or 4 spaces or a tab or however much you want to indent by. This needs to be done after each `\n` character.

You can then put `<newRoot>\n` at the start of the string, and `\n</newRoot>` at the end of the string.

Note: this will only work "as intended" for already formatted XML input strings. In other words, if you give it

```
<t1>
  <t2>
    <t3>
  </t3>
  </t2>
</t1>
```

(which is not consistently indented)

It will give you the same inner XML back, but with 1 consistent level of indentation added:

```
<t0>
  <t1>
    <t2>
      <t3>
    </t3>
    </t2>
  </t1>
</t0>
```

Comment: Thanks toastedDevil :) I will work on your suggestion.

Comment: If you add spaces or tabs after every newline character, that will include newlines within significant text nodes, which will corrupt the textual content of the document.

Comment: You're completely right, I didn't think of that. In that case, does it need to be parsed? Any pattern you try to match could appear in the text and cause it to become corrupted as you pointed out.